# Specific folder access rules for specific users with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

With the settings below, both `user-1` and `user-2` can access to `site-1` and `site-2` after login. However, I want to change access rights as listed below:

- `user-1` can access only `site-1` (`http://test.local/site-1`)
- `user-2` can access only `site-2` (`http://test.local/site-2`)

How can I do it?

**Site structure**

```
test
   site-1
      index.php
   site-2
      index.php
   index.php
   .htaccess
   .htpasswd
```

**.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Test Site"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/local/test/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd**

```
user-1:$apr1$CraA.0n7$JRqS7GyggMKNYcTP65rAW/
user-2:$apr1$NbKoZeyJ$P33C/1ceg1XGfLaPsWBgW1
```

**test.local.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.local

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/local/test

        <Directory /var/www/html/local/test>
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with what I did above in OP, I solved the problem with creating additional .htaccess files right inside `site-1` and `site-2` so the contents are:

**site-1/.htaccess**

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/local/test/.htpasswd
Require user user-1
```

**site-2/.htaccess**

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/local/test/.htpasswd
Require user user-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change:

```
Require valid-user
```

to:

```
Require user user-1
```

alternatively create yourself two group files, and change the line to something along the following lines:

```
Require group siteOneUsers
```

see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require